# Count specific categories in multiple columns and multiplicate them with a sum row

Tags: r, count, sum

I want to count how often each category occurs at my dataframe.

To do so I need to count the category in each row and multiply this number with the sum of column 5.

(column c4 is not necessary for my analysis)

Preferred output would be:

Analytics = 131

Ads= 253

Identification= ..

My data looks like this:

```
tracker_category <- data.frame = c("Tracker1", "Tracker2", "Tracker3", "Tracker4","Tracker5","Tracker6"), 
c1 = c("Analytics", "Crash", "Location", "Identification", "Analytics", "Ads"), 
c2 = c("Ads", "Analytics", "Location", "Analytics", "Identification", "Ads"), 
c3 = c("Identification", "Analytics", "Ads", "Ads", "Analytics", "Location"),
c4 = c("url1.com","ur2.com","url3.com","url4.com","url5.com","url6.com"),
sum_tracker = c(1,20,100,0,5,76))
```

Comment: `table(unlist(tracker_Category[2:3]))`?

Comment: Hi, in this case it counts just the name once. I need it to be multilied with the related sum form sum_trackers.  The calculation Analytics is : First Row 1*1 +Second Row 2*20/ +Third row 0*100 etc..

Comment: what exactly are you doing? what is 1*1, 2*20, 0*100?? where do you get the 1,2,0 from?

Comment: @Paul could you check my proposed answer and whether your total for Analytics is correct? If so, I have not understood your algorithm. But with `{tidyr}`'s `pivot_longer()` you should get a table that allows you to create the total value per row that you are after, and you can then add over these values by row again with `group_by()` and `summarise()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should produce what you are after.
You can convert your data frame in "long" format and then add the occurrences (your column 5).

**data**
Note: to support reproducibility, I corrected your data frame definition.

```
tracker_category <- data.frame(
id = c("Tracker1", "Tracker2", "Tracker3", "Tracker4","Tracker5","Tracker6"), 
c1 = c("Analytics", "Crash", "Location", "Identification", "Analytics", "Ads"), 
c2 = c("Ads", "Analytics", "Location", "Analytics", "Identification", "Ads"), 
c3 = c("Identification", "Analytics", "Ads", "Ads", "Analytics", "Location"),
c4 = c("url1.com","ur2.com","url3.com","url4.com","url5.com","url6.com"),
sum_tracker = c(1,20,100,0,5,76)
)
```

**coerce to long format**
`{tidyr}` provides a `pivot_longer()` function for this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tracker_category %>% 
  select(-c4) %>%       # remove c4
  pivot_longer( cols = c(c1:c3)           # which cols to use
              , names_to = "action"       # where to store the names
              , values_to = "categories") # and values
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 4
   id       sum_tracker action categories    
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  <chr>         
 1 Tracker1           1 c1     Analytics     
 2 Tracker1           1 c2     Ads           
 3 Tracker1           1 c3     Identification
 4 Tracker2          20 c1     Crash         
 5 Tracker2          20 c2     Analytics     
 6 Tracker2          20 c3     Analytics     
 7 Tracker3         100 c1     Location      
 8 Tracker3         100 c2     Location      
 9 Tracker3         100 c3     Ads           
10 Tracker4           0 c1     Identification
11 Tracker4           0 c2     Analytics     
12 Tracker4           0 c3     Ads           
13 Tracker5           5 c1     Analytics     
14 Tracker5           5 c2     Identification
15 Tracker5           5 c3     Analytics     
16 Tracker6          76 c1     Ads           
17 Tracker6          76 c2     Ads           
18 Tracker6          76 c3     Location
```

From that format you can perform `summarise()` on your groups with `{dplyr}`.

```
tracker_category %>% 
   select(-c4) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = c(c1:c3), names_to = "action", values_to = "categories") %>% 
#------------- group by your categories
   group_by(categories) %>% 
#------------- and sum over your tracked results, note to use sum and not multiplication as we used a long format
   summarise(total = sum(sum_tracker))
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  categories     total
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 Ads              253
2 Analytics         51
3 Crash             20
4 Identification     6
5 Location         276
```

Please check whether your Analytics example of 131 is really correct ...